# Kendo doesn't load some of the culture messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to localize Kendo for my app. My language wasn't originally supported, so I added my localized version to `messages/kendo.messages.xx-XX.min.js`

2. I added this line to my `web.config`:
   `<globalization uiCulture="xx-XX" culture="xx-XX"></globalization>`
3. And I've included these scripts under kendo's scripts:

`<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1314/kendo.culture.xx-XX.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1314/messages/kendo.messages.xx-XX.min.js"></script>`

Kendo still shows some of the English messages for my grid view. If I change `uiCulture` value to `en-US` it doesn't load English file and still shows my edited version. But any value other than `en-US` works fine and Kendo uses its localized messages. And yes, I'm sure I've not accidently edited `en-US` file... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really absent minded. I should answer this question for anyone with similar issue. As it's been noted in [Kendo's documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#adding-new-localizations) `.js` files have nothing to do with a MVC application. You have to:

1. Open `Kendo.Mvc.sln` solution.
2. In the `Resources` folder, copy `Messages.resx` file and rename it with your culture code, e.g., `Messages.en-US`.
3. Rebuild solution as `Release`.
4. Copy `Kendo.Mvc.dll` file and your culture code folder from `bin/release` folder to `lib/KENDOUIMVC/{Date}` folder of your project.
5. Set `uiCulture` value of `Globalization` tag in your `web.config` file and you're good to go!

Answer (score 3):

See [Kendo Globalization Overview](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview).

Add this to your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@{
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1314/kendo.culture." + culture + ".min.js")"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    kendo.culture("@culture");
</script>
```

Example:

[image: Kendo Culture]

Comment: Thanks Vash, but it didn't work. I get true value for `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name` and in VS I can see my files being loaded, but I still have the issue. There's another thing, my kendo doesn't seem to have a `culture` variable, but just `cultures`.

Comment: Are you using globalize.js, and using kendo.culture() after loading the kendo scripts?

Comment: I've put the script after kendo ones, but I don't have any `globalize.js`.

Comment: I've read that link and that's exactly what I'm doing. I have set culture value in my `web.config` as well.